# How to set version to your war in WildFly?

Tags: tomcat, version, wildfly, wildfly-8

In apache I use, projectname#1.9-Test##1.9-TEST to set version my war.
What is the equivalent of that in WildFly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildfly doesn't have the parallel deployment feature that tomcat has. As far as I know this feature is pretty unique to Tomcat.

There is a feature request in the Wildfly Jira for this:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4701

but IMO it is going to be a long time before we see this. It is much harder to implement this feature in a full app server than it is in a servlet container. Since the app server is responsible for providing core services there is no easy way handle multiple deployments at once.  For example, if you have a message in the JMS queue and there are two versions of the .war file listening on the queue, the object may be unable to serialize in one of the deployments and not the other.

The typical way of doing this is to handle session expiration at the load balancer. There is a discussion of this in the JBoss forums:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/236663

Comment: you can do it in weblogic, in your example I would make the old war stop listening to the message queue.