# How to deploy a new version of a Java application completely transparent to the users?

Tags: session, java-8, continuous-deployment, wildfly-10

I'm needing an answer or tutorial explaining how to solve the following scenario:

- We have a server runnning Java 8 and Wildfly 10;
- We already have a war deployed. Let call it `system_v1.war`;
- We would like to deploy a new version of this application, `system_v2.war`, with the following pre-requisites:

  - The actual version, system_v1.war, should keep running when the new version, system_v2.war is deploying;
  - The user sessions should be kept and the deploy should be transparent to them;
  - When the new version, system_v2.war, is already deployed, all user sessions, kept in system_v1.war, should migrate to the new version, system_v2.war;
  - When all user sessions had migrated, we undeploy system_v1.war;
  - So, now, we have just one version, system_v2.war, with the new features developed, and this migration was completely transparent to the current and new users of the application.

How can we do this?

If we are using PHP, for example, this isn't a big deal, we need just send the new file to the server and everything is ok. No user will know, all sessions will be kept and the new features come in. So the question is how to do this with Java.

Using Tomcat, we can name our wars with ##001, ##002, for example, and this does a transparent application deploy. In this way the user sessions gradually migrate to the new version. But isn't clear to me if  we undeploy the old version immediately we will lose the users sessions in the version one or not. But, if we don't lose the user sessions, (and I would like to know if this is true too), how to do this with Wildfly 10?

Comment: Please see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004494/how-to-set-version-to-your-war-in-wildfly